# Grails SSL certificate error

Tags: grails, ssl

I'm using the acegi security plugin and I run the app -https. The cert is generated but I get a certificate warning when i visit the web page. I have then download the weak ssl plugin and added `weakssl.trustAll =true` to `Config.groovy`. But still getting the same warning. Have I left out anything?

Comment: Do you get the warning in the browser? If so you need a certificate issued from a Certificate Authority that your browser trusts. Something like Verisign.

Comment: Btw. if any of the posted answers suits you be sure to mark it as correct. That way your accept rating will go up and the other users are even more likely to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is normal. You can just accept the self-signed certificate. The weakssl module allows the Grails *server* to trust *itself* even if it provides a self-signed certificate. It has no effect whatsoever on the client. (Think what a horrible security hole it would be if you could just install some code on the *server* and get a *client* to accept a self-signed certificate without a warning!)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to either

- manually tell your browser the certificate is OK by adding the certificate to your truststore

or

- get a certificate from a trusted CA (Certificate Authority) a list of trusted CAs is stored in your browser. To get a certififate from a CA you need to proof your identity and pay (a lot) some money.

so I recommend you just accept the untrusted certifcate unless you want to buy a CA certificate.

The config you changed tells **only the server** to accept all certificates. i.e. if your server is connecting to another server

Comment: There are also free certificates from StartSSL.